# Add Hover Feature On Product Image

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid, liquid-layout

I am trying to add a feature to show an alternative product picture when the cursor hovers over the product image in a collection view.

Whenever I view the page with the code below, the product images have shifted to the bottom of the container and also cover the Title/Price that was below them.

What can I correct to keep the pictures in their original alignment and have only the hover effect work?

Thank you!

Here is what I currently have in product-card-grid.liquid --

```
<div id="{{ wrapper_id }}" class="grid-view-item__image-wrapper js">
    <div style="padding-top:{% unless product.featured_image == blank %}{{ 1 | divided_by: product.featured_image.aspect_ratio | times: 100}}%{% else %}100%{% endunless %};">
     <div class="reveal">
      <img id="{{ img_id }}"
            class="grid-view-item__image lazyload"
            src="{{ product.featured_image | img_url: '300x300' }}"
            data-src="{{ img_url }}"
            data-widths="[180, 360, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1296, 1512, 1728, 2048]"
            data-aspectratio="{{ product.featured_image.aspect_ratio }}"
            data-sizes="auto"
            alt="">
      <img id="{{img_id}}"
           class="hidden" 
           src="{{ product.images.last }}"
           data-src="{{ img_url }} "
           data-widths="[180, 360, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1296, 1512, 1728, 2048]"
           data-aspectratio="{{ product.featured_image.aspect_ratio }}"
           data-sizes="auto"
           alt="{{ product.images.last.alt | escape }}">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The css for "Reveal" is below:

```
  /* ===============================================
// Reveal module
// =============================================== */

.reveal .hidden { display: block !important; visibility: visible !important;}
.product:hover .reveal img { opacity: 1; }
.reveal { position: relative; }
.reveal .hidden { 
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;  
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;  
}
.reveal:hover .hidden { 
  z-index: 100000;
  opacity: 1;    
}
.reveal .caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;  
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white; /* fallback for IE8 */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font: 13px/1.6 sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #333;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
.reveal .hidden .caption .centered {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  .reveal .caption { 
    font-size: 11px; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem does not come from the `width: 100%; height: 100%;` specified for `.reveal .hidden`? By just reading this, it seems it will stretch the image to be revealed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work with the following

In the CSS, I had the @media (hover:hover){} so that users do not have to double click an image on mobile to go to the product page.

CSS:

```
/* ===============================================
// Reveal module
// =============================================== */
@media (hover:hover) {
.has-secondary.grid-view-item__link img.secondary{
 display:none;
}
}

@media (hover:hover) {
.has-secondary.grid-view-item__link:hover img.secondary{
 display:block;
}
}

@media (hover:hover) {
.has-secondary.grid-view-item__link:hover img.grid-view-item__image{
 display:none;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width:767px){
.has-secondary.grid-view-item__link img.secondary{
 display:none;
}

.has-secondary.grid-view-item__link:hover img.secondary{
 display:block;
}

.has-secondary.grid-view-item__link:hover img.grid-view-item__image{
 display:none;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px){
.has-secondary.grid-view-item__link img.secondary{
 display:none;
}
}
```

Changed product-card-grid.liquid HTML/Liquid to the following:

```
{% unless grid_image_width %}
  {%- assign grid_image_width = '600x600' -%}
{% endunless %}
<div class="grid-view-item{% unless product.available %} product-price--sold-out grid-view-item--sold-out{% endunless %}">
  <a class="grid-view-item__link {% if product.images.size > 1 %} has-secondary{% endif %}" href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}">
    <img class="grid-view-item__image" src="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: grid_image_width }}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt }}">
    {% if product.images.size > 1 %}
     <img class="secondary" src="{{ product.images.last | img_url: grid_image_width }}" alt="{{ product.images.last.alt | escape }}">
    {% endif %}
  </a>
</div>

<div class="h4 grid-view-item__title">
     <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}"> {{ product.title }} </a>
</div>   
{% if section.settings.show_vendor %}
      <div class="grid-view-item__vendor">{{ product.vendor }}</div>
    {% endif %}
 <div class="grid-view-item__meta">
   <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}"> {% include 'product-price', variant: product %} </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot going on in your CSS, but if I understand the sitaution correctly you want to achieve an effect like the one in [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/alaman/pen/YvvqXb), right?

In your CSS, absolutely position two images inside of a div (with `top: 0px` and `left: 0px`) and change the opacity of the top image in the stack by hovering on the parent.

HTML:

```
<div class='reveal'>
  <img src='image_src' class='bottom'>
  <img src='image_src' class='top'>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.top, .bottom {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.frame:hover .top {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** Implementation w/ grid, as requested.

HTML:

```
<div class='grid'>
    <div class='reveal'>
      <img src='image_src' class='bottom'>
      <img src='image_src' class='top'>
    </div>
    <div class='reveal'>
      <img src='image_src' class='bottom'>
      <img src='image_src' class='top'>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /*makes the grid "responsive"*/
}

.reveal {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 200px; /*last value must be picture width*/
  height:200px; /* picture height*/
  margin: 20px; /*aesthetic only*/
  position: relative;
}

.top, .bottom {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%; /*centers pictures inside flex children (.reveal divs)*/
  transform: translate(-50%, 0); /*see above*/
}

.reveal:hover .top {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

[Demo on Codepen](https://codepen.io/alaman/pen/VddxWx?editors=1100)

The above example uses flexbox to create a simple grid which will work with the (slightly modified) `.reveal` divs from my original post. If you're unfamiliar with flexbox syntax, there's an awesome [free video course](https://flexbox.io) from Wes Bos that I highly recommend.

P.S. Note that the grid will only work "out of the box" if the images have a set pixel width, although you could easily support different images sizes with a little media query magic.

Comment: This is close to what I need but it causes the grid to become messed up.

Comment: I updated my post to include an example of how the technique can be used within the context of a grid. It relies heavily on flexbox though so make sure you're familiar with the syntax if you plan to use it. :)

Comment: That's perfect there! Thank you so much!